# display blog category name through blog category id in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have a module for a blog in that I have different categories now I want print category name in phtml file through category id in magento2 I am getting category id 
code to display category id

```
<?php
$categoryIds = $_post->getCategories();
print_r($categoryIds);
?>
```

through this code blog category id is coming now i want to display title

Comment: which blog extension you are using?

Comment: can you post whole phtml code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$title = $_post->getParentCategories()->getTitle();  
echo $title;
```